# Port forwarding for localhost traffic over SSH to production machine database

Tags: mysql, ssh, port-forwarding

On windows I used to use Bitvise Tunnler to foward all traffic on my PC's localhost:33306 over an SSH connection to my server - and then from there to the mysqlserver:3306 server database.

```
PC:33306 -> server:3306 -> databaseserver:3306
```

Now that I'm using linux I find that it is easy to SSH anywhere anytime with:

```
ssh user@site.tld
```

However, I'm not sure how to replicate this port forwarding using the ssh options. If it was just from one computer to another I think I could do something like this...

```
ssh -L 33306:localhost:3306 user@site.com
```

**UPDATE**

I have tried connecting using the following SSH and the connection seems to work.

```
ssh -L 33306:localhost:3306 user@otherserver.com
```

But phpMyAdmin throws this error when trying to connect to the other server

```
#1045 - Access denied for user '[[user]]'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Then I tried

```
ssh -L 33306:db.server.com:3306 user@otherserver.com
```

and phpMyAdmin threw this error

```
#1045 - Access denied for user '[[user]]'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

running *netstat -an | more* shows

```
tcp6       0      0 ::1:33306               :::*                    LISTEN
```

Again, the process flow should look like this:

```
mypc -> server -> otherdbserveronprivatelan
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do:

ssh -L 33306:databaseserver:3306 user@site.com

Comment: Well, it opens the SSH channel and it doesn't complain about anything. But how do I know it's working? Trying to use phpmyadmin over it isn't working so I need to know if that is my config or if the connection didn't take.

Answer (score 0):

It did work. However, I was still using "localhost" instead of "127.0.0.1" when trying to connect.

> For the command line ssh, this is
>
> ssh -L
>   3333:mysqlhostname.youdomain.com:3306
>   shelluser@yourdomain.com
>
> You then open connections in your
>   mysql frontend to 127.0.0.1 port 3333.
>   Note that it must be 127.0.0.1, not
>   localhost, as the later would use UNIX
>   domain sockets.

http://blog.dreamhosters.com/kbase/index.cgi?area=2991

Answer (score 0):

This is **not** a ssh issue but rather a MySQL one. For MySQL, you need to ensure that the user has been granted access to that database. This is typically done with a:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON dbname.* TO 'username'@'host' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

The main thing to note here is the `'host'` setting. Since you are tunneling over SSH, you need to be `'username'@'localhost'` in order to work. The wildcard setting of `'username'@'%'` will not work for localhost connections.

Comment: Thanks, but as stated already, the problem was using *localhost* instead of *127.0.0.1* because of UNIX domain sockets.